# Ошибка You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: веб-программирование, php, sql, mysql

*Здесь была огромная простыня кода и скриншот, которые не имеют никакого отношения к SQL-ошибке. Из-за этого собственно ошибки были не видны. Проблемный код и текст ошибки оставлены ([[@Khvorostin](/users/7295/khvorostin)](/users/7295/khvorostin))*

```
<?php

  $pos = mysql_query( "SELECT `признак_посещения`
                        WHERE 'фио_студента' == $stud_array[$f]
                          AND 'имя_работы'   == $work_array[$t] ")
         or die( mysql_error() );
?>
```

выдает

```
> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to
> your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near 'where
> 'фио_студента'==Исаев Алексей and
> 'имя_раб' at line 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Формально говоря, такое будет работать.

Но любой человек, знакомый с базами данных, будет плеваться на этот код: обращение к базе данных стоит «дорого» (то есть, забирает много времени и ресурсов системы). Поэтому лучше сделать один запрос, который выдаст вам сразу все нужные данные, и потом уж разобрать его в ваши структуры данных.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where 'фио_студента'==Исаев Алексей and 'имя_раб' at line 1 что не так=(? обновил код  в вопросе

Comment: Я имею в виду теоретическую возможность. Понятно, что надо сперва починить синтаксис.

Comment: извините. как правильней будет синтаксис?

Answer (score 5):

'фио_студента'==Исаев Алексей

1. не ==, а =
2. текст не закавычен

Общее замечание. Не стыдно такой говнокод показывать?

1. *echo* где не надо, дикая смесь HTML, PHP и SQL
2. несколько запросов к БД в рамках одной страницы, SQL-запросы в цикле
3. SQL-запросы типа SELECT * FROM
4. бардак в оформлении - кривые отступы, отстутствие единства в оформлении кода: первый запрос вынесен в отдельую переменную, три другие - нет
5. Кое-как составленные таблицы, потерянные теги <tr>, незакртые теги, вложенные таблицы там, где это не нужно.

все это, как минимум, неуважение к тем, кто видит ваш код.

Попробуйте сделать так:

- Единственный запрос к БД.
- Обработка данных, результаты складываются в массив.
- Вывод результатов. Максимум HTML, минимум PHP (только *foreach...*, никаких *echo*)